# While loop with += (Addition Assignment) shows just last resoult

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop, variable-assignment

I have a sql table for storing temp data

```
create table TempDataStore (ID int, HtmlCode NVARCHAR(max))
```

I populate this table with while loop

```
while @cnt < 3
BEGIN
set @html = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),dilos.report.CreateHTMLTable(
(
select  * from  dilos.report.getHESExpress(cast(@site as varchar))
order by status,SendungsNr offset 0+@cnt*4 rows fetch next 4 rows only FOR XML PATH('row'),ELEMENTS XSINIL),null,'',''))
insert into TempDataStore values(@cnt+1, @html)
set @cnt = @cnt +1
end
```

This is used to convert sql to html table and divide query results  to 4 rows.

Now I want to create a nvarchar(MAX) variable called @htmlSummary to display every row from TempDataStore  as one html code (string/nvachar).

```
while @cnt<3 --just some number
begin
set @htmlSummary = '<p><h3>Express Orders</h3>' +coalesce(replace((select HtmlCode from TempDataStore where id =@cnt+1),'<table border="1" style="font-size:40px;','<table class="table-sm table-striped"'),'') +'</p>' 
set @htmlSummary +=@htmlSummary 
set @cnt =@cnt+1
END

select @htmlSummary
```

The problem is that at the end @htmlSummary stores just the last row of TempDataStore  table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: The DBMS is MS SQL

Comment: `set @htmlSummary +=@htmlSummary` is preceded by `set @htmlSummary = '...'`, which obviously overwrites `@htmlSummary`. Use two separate variables, or alternatively, merge the two statements into one: `set @htmlSummary += '...'`

Comment: If there is a way to dynamically declare variables that would solve my problem. What I mean is I have a table that has 20 rows and I would like to change it to  html so that in one nvarchar  would have 5 rows saved in html table. For that I would need variables html1, html2, html3 , html4. I could't find a way too declare variables in a loop with sql. That's why I use TempDataStore table.

I don't understand why this example works:
DECLARE v1 VARCHAR(40);  
SET v1 = 'This is the original.';  
SET v1 += ' More text.';  
select  v1; 
but in my loop only the last row is saved.